# Ubuntu not connecting to internet but is connected to lan

Tags: networking

I have a HP DL165 G5p and I have it plugged into my TL-R600VPN.

It is able to have a LAN IP assigned although it is not able to connect to the internet and it is not able to resolve IPs from hostnames (host google.ca) or ping IPs, It cannot ping my default gateway either although it can ping other devices on the network. I have my computer and other server connected to the same router and they both work fine.

I have looked at the other articles I was able to find on here and nothing was able to solve my problem. Thanks.

I am using Ubuntu Server 16.04

- ifconfig: http://prntscr.com/jlg2ue
- ping google.ca: http://prntscr.com/jlg334
- host google.ca: http://prntscr.com/jlg3b3
- ping 8.8.8.8: http://prntscr.com/jlg3fx
- Unable to do traceroute because I cannot connect to the internet to install it.
- ifup and ifdown did not fix it.
- IP route: http://prntscr.com/jlu5pe

Is it possible my built-in NIC is incompatible?

Comment: what is the output `ifconfig`

Comment: share the output of `traceroute`

Comment: try this command `sudo ifdown interfacename` & `sudo ifup interfacename`

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `ip route show`. Also, please include `ping 192.168.0.1` (press Ctrl-C after a few seconds). Do you have any other computers or devices behind your router that are working? If not, you may have a larger problem (something with the router -> your ISP).

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?  (Important for the next question I ask)

Comment: I don't want to worry you for nothing but I just saw your router model in the news: https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2018/05/hackers-infect-500000-consumer-routers-all-over-the-world-with-malware/ May be try a reset of the router and update the firmware ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I don't want to worry you for nothing but I just saw your router model in the news: arstechnica.com/information-technology/2018/05/… May be try a reset of the router and update the firmware ??" – solsTiCe

Resetting the router managed to work. Not really sure though why.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess:

```
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1
```

It really looks like you don't have a default route.

Ok, so that wasn't it.

But it looks like something is broken with the connectivity between your router and your computer -- your results from pinging it shows no response, and almost every router out there allows pinging it on the LAN side.

Comment: It just said file already exists & ip route showed "default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp6s0f1
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp6s0f1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.112
"